# JQuery Append Text Dynamically by Onblur input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i give input (1) then its successfully append text. But when i erase then input value  and again give input(2) then its increasing with previous value(1+2=3). Where loop count previous and present value

[image: first i gave 1 then append 1text then i again give 1 then it append two text. Where loop count previous and present value]

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $("#flatcount").blur(function() {
            var floor = (this).value;
                for(i=1;i<=floor;i++) {
                    $('#row').append('<p>This is appended text</p><br>');
                }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  empty the element.before append like  [`$('#row').empty()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil3OPH5Z7UAhVKQo8KHZXHCgsQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fempty%2F&usg=AFQjCNHDHWvdVJynA8qRbLtMUNyU5AzKSw&sig2=C6zddQyvtMGQZ7Rd7Zmsrw)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#flatcount").blur(function() {
    var floor = $(this).val();
    $('#row').empty() //empty
    for (i = 1; i <= floor; i++) {
      $('#row').append('<p>This is appended text</p><br>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="flatcount">
<p id="row"></p>
```

Comment: Thank U so much . Very Helpful Answer .

Answer (score 1):

use this code i think it will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $("#flatcount").blur(function() {
               $("#row").empty();
               var floor = (this).value;
                for(i=1;i<=floor;i++) {
                    $('#row').append('<p>This is appended text</p><br>');
                }
    });
});
```